# Iptables-legacy with Normal Iptables in Debian Buster

Tags: debian, iptables

Debian Buster has a mess with iptables. There are two sets running. The first one is called iptables-legacy and the second one is just normal iptables. It took m 2 hours to figure that out because none of these two worked correctly. Experimentally, I made these two work by setting them both like this:

```
iptables-legacy -I INPUT.. the rest of the stuff goes here
```

and

```
iptables - I INPUT.. the rest of the stuff goes here
```

All the other chains are created the same way and it seems to work OK now.

Now my question is how do I clean up this Debian Buster mess and to keep just one "normal" iptables and to remove this iptables-legacy nonsense? It's a clean / fresh install of Buster from packages without me doing / adding anything extra at all.

Would appreciate any comments / suggestions / pointers at all. Many thanks in advance!

P.S. Where does iptables-legacy save a file with its rules?

Answer (score 5):

Debian Buster is using [nftables](https://wiki.debian.org/nftables) instead of the previous iptables, but it's still available as `iptables-legacy`. When I added a rule via Webmin 1.941, this was added to iptables-legacy, but moved to iptables on reboot.

`/usr/sbin/iptables` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/iptables` which in turn is a symlink to `/usr/sbin/iptables-nft`.

You can convert your current rules like this (see [details](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Moving_from_iptables_to_nftables)):

```
iptables-restore-translate -f /etc/iptables/rules.v4 > ruleset.nft
nft -f ruleset.nft
```

Removing iptables:

```
apt-get purge iptables netfilter-persistent+
```

Haven't done this myself yet, so make sure to test if persistence works.